# .sort (reverse=True) moving 10 to the bottom

Tags: python, sorting

Your score is >>> 10

Do you want to take the quiz again? Y or N: n
5 : hotty

5 : 2qa3ws8ujhyi9;[]\']

2 : zzzz

2 : y

10 : TEST

Goodbye!

```
template = """{score} : {name}"""
display_good = template.format(score=score,name=user_name)  
highscore_a = open("highscoreFile.txt",'a') #The file that keeps the highest scores of all time
highscore_a.write(display_good)
highscore_a.write('\n')
highscore_a.close()
highscore_r = open("highscoreFile.txt", "r") 

read_top_5 = highscore_r.readlines()
read_top_5.sort(reverse=True)
i =[5]

repeat = (read_top_5[-5:])
for i in repeat:
    print(i)
```

Comment: You probably want to convert those to `int` rather than sorting them as strings.

Comment: This is expected behaviour when sorting **strings**.

Comment: Thanks, would I just make the score an int? Because I cant make the name an int

Answer (score 0):

You can record the score and sort it as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path  # python3.6+
record_fmt = """{score} : {name}"""
record = record_fmt.format(score=score, name=user_name)  
record_path = Path("highscoreFile.txt")
with record_path.open('a') as fp:
    fp.write(f'{record}\n') 

records = record_path.read_text().strip().split('\n')
top_5 = sorted(records, key=lambda x: -int(x.strip().split(':')[0].strip()))[:5]
print('\n'.join(top_5))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to understand what I am writing as it is for school